Remote Extension host terminated unexpectedly 3 times within the last 5 minutes
We're encountering a peculiar issue with the Visual Studio Code (VS Code) Remote SSH Extension on from my Windows Local Machine. While other developers can seamlessly connect to our Ubuntu server using VS Code, one particular developer (myself) consistently faces the error message: "Remote Extension host terminated unexpectedly 3 times within the last 5 minutes." Curiously, regular SSH connections work fine for me. Despite attempts to reinstall both VS Code and the Remote SSH extension, the issue persists. Could someone shed light on why this might be happening and offer potential solutions? Your insights would be immensely valuable.
attempted to reinstall both VS Code and the Remote SSH extension, even tried to pause antivirus.
